# Cauchy problem and global solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, cauchy-problem

Let $y(x)$ the unique solution of the Cauchy problem

\begin{cases}
y'(x)=\sqrt{\ln(1+y(x)^2)}
\\
y(0)=y_0
\end{cases}

i) Show that, for $y_0>0$, $y(x)$ is strictly increasing and convex.

ii) Show that $y(x)$ is globally defined.

---

For i), I note that $$\ln(1+y(x)^2) = 0  \text{ iff } y(x)=0$$

So, if $y(0)=0$, then $y(x)=0$ is the unique solution.

If $y_0>0$, then in a right neighbourhood of $x=0$ I have that $y'(x)>0$. Also, by uniqueness, I can't  cross the stationary solution $y(x)=0$, and therefore $$y'(x)=\ln(\sqrt{1+y^2})>0$$ for every $x>0$. Since this is the rhs of the equation, this proves that the function is strictly increasing.

To show convexity, I just computed $$y''(x)= \frac{y y'(x)}{1+y(x)^2} >0 $$ since $y'(x)>0$ and $y(x)>0$ by uniqueness.

ii) Here I don't know how to argue formally. It is clear from a picture that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y(x)=+\infty$, but I don't know how to show that $y(x)$ is globally defined.

Comment: The RHside of your ODE seems to be sublinear in $y$. ;-)

Comment: thanks @Pacciu. How can I show it explicitly? I've never done it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) := \sqrt{\log(1 + y^2)}$ be the RH side of your ODE.
 Since $\log$ is concave, you have $\log(1+t) \leq t$ for every $t >-1$ therefore:

$\log(1 + y^2) \leq y^2\quad \Rightarrow\quad f(x,y) \leq \sqrt{y^2} = |y|$

and $f(x,y)$ is sublinear in $y$ (uniformly w.r.t. $x$).
Now classical global existence theorems apply and *ii* follows.

Comment: It's clear, I didn't manage do use concavity, doh. About i), is everything okay? @Pacciu

Comment: Yes, *i* is ok. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know some books where I can find plenty of exercises like this one? They're nice :)

Comment: I have just one reference (and it is in Italian): Acerbi, Modica & Spagnolo (1986) **Problemi Scelti di Analisi Matematica II**, Liguori Ed., Napoli.

Comment: @andereBen If you find some other references, could you let me know? Thnx in advance.

Comment: I was given a similar exercise, I don't know the source, but here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791010/cauchy-problem-prove-positiveness